# Как заменить символы в строке?

Tags: php, strlen

Есть строка:

> verstala@website.com

*Вопрос*:

Как заменить в данной строке все символы до @ и исключить первый символ и последний до @, на `*`. То есть должно получиться вот так:

> v******a@website.com

Как реализовать данную задачу?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "verstala@website.com";
$pos = stripos($str, "@");
for($i=1; $i < $pos - 1; $i++) $str[$i] = "*";
echo $str; //Выводит v******a@website.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "verstala@website.com";
// При условии, что строка валидный мейл
// Первая часть это имя пользователя, вторая адрес почты
preg_match('/(?<hide>.+)@(?<addr>.+)/', $str, $matches);
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// $matches['hide'][0] - первая буква 
$hide_name = $matches['hide'][0] . str_repeat("*", strlen($matches['hide']) - 1);
// 
echo sprintf("%s@%s", $hide_name, $matches['addr']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$str = 'verstala@website.com';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~(?<=[\pL\d]).+(?=[\pL\d]@)~',
    function($a){ return str_repeat('*', strlen($a[0])); },
    $str
);
```